# Is it possible to start and stop a Docker Container upon .NET solution debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, debugging, .net-core

I am wondering whether that would be possible to start a docker container / docker compose at the the same time that a .NET Core solution core is started to be debugged and stop it when the solution is no longer debugged.

Comment: I think this is exactly what happens when you check the box "Include docker support" when creating a new project. You might want to have alook at that and see what it's doing.

Comment: except that the your project is considered as a container too which can be troublesome if you expect some stdin interaction with: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061481/visual-studio-how-to-change-the-docker-compose-command-used-to-debug-a-dockeriz